# Issues with C++ Precision

Tags: c++

I saw a number of posts which spoke about how we can display a number with a given precision in C++, but I was wondering if there is a way to display non recurring numbers as say x.0 and recurring numbers of width specified by the setprecision method?

Comment: What's a recurring number?

Comment: something like 26.38888887514183 now the numbers will start repeating from 3888 etc. while it is not so with the case of 1.0.

Comment: That's the default behavior. `setprecision` sets the *maximum* number of decimal places. If less are required then less are used. `std::fixed` can force a certain number of decimal places (i.e. pad with 0 if needed).

Comment: @KrishnaBharadwaj: correct me if I am wrong, but in Number Theory, that isn't a strict recurring/repeated number (as recurring/repeated numbers are periodic), that's actually a non-periodic recurring number - much like you'll find in obscure places in the decimal places of pi.

Comment: @jrd1, it was probably a repeating number in decimal that was rounded to binary. All binary numbers can be converted back to an exact decimal number if you allow enough digits.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Ah! I see your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you knew in advance whether the number you want to print exhibits a recurring decimal expansion, then you could simply issue an statement along the lines of:

```
if is_recurring:
    print using expanded format
else
    print using fixed format
```

I imagine you do not know in advance. And the computer cannot, in general, know it either.

How would it test whether a few decimals (about 15 if you are using double precision) represent a recurring decimal?

Furthermore, how would you like to print it? Take, for instance, the classical example:

```
3227 / 555 = 5.814414414414414
```

How should I print it? Like this?

```
5.8144
```

or like that?

```
5.8144
   ***
```

It seems like a very difficult problem to address in general.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is to trim trailing zeroes. The machine doesn't know whether a number is really a "recurring number," which is just a fancy name for a rational number whose denominator is relatively prime from the numeric base, because floating point math is not based on rational numbers.

As Adam mentioned, the default output style is already to omit trailing zeroes. This hasn't much to do with math; it's just deleting the characters from the end of the string.

In terms of the Standard, the `ios_base::fixed` and `ios_base::scientific` flags determine qualitative formatting. If neither is set, the output is equivalent to the `%g` format specifier of `printf`.

According to `man printf`,

> Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears only if it is followed by at least one digit.

To get a `.0` at the end despite the above rule, you would have to do something like print to a temporary string, search it for a decimal point, and retry in `fixed` mode if not found.